# Installing pandas 0.20.3 on Google Cloud Dataflow takes a very long time

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

When using the Apache Beam Python SDK 2.0.0 on Google Cloud Dataflow, it takes forever (about 8 minutes) to install Pandas 0.20.3. The install mainly hangs on the message `Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pandas: still running...`. On my machine, however, installing the same version of pandas doesn't even take 30 seconds (even after clearing pip cache). Installing pandas takes about a third of the cost of running my pipeline right now. Any ideas on why this takes so much time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dataflow SDK stages dependencies in source only form because the client architecture does not necessarily match the VMs used as Dataflow workers. This will cause pandas to be installed from sources and compiled on the VMs taking a long time.

It is possible to solve this by using the `--extra_package` flag and pointing to a `whl` file. For pandas you can use the corresponding `whl` file (py27, x86_64) from the pypi page of [pandas](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas).

Comment: I tried this with 'pandas-0.20.3-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl', but unfortunately it failed with `10:43:47.000
Failed to install packages: failed to install extra packages: failed to install extra package pandas-0.20.3-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl: exit status 1`. Any idea what might be wrong? Is the architecture different after all?

Comment: Never mind! I had to use the cp27mu version. It works now. Thank you!!!